# Exibir vários registros dentro de um só no MySQL

Tags: sql, mysqli, select

tenho uma dúvida quanto a montagem de um select.

Eu tenho 3 tabelas que se relacionam M:N da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente eu estou usando esse sql:

```
select p.descricao,
       (select descricao from item where item.codigo = c.codigoItem) as items  
from produto p inner join composicao c on c.codigoProduto = p.codigo 
inner join item i on i.codigo = c.codigoItem 
order by p.codigo
```

e o resultado vem assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Beleza, porém seria possível fazer uma saída como na imagem abaixo direto pelo sql?

Tem alguma função para definir um *group by* ou teria que montar uma *stored procedure*? A princípio eu estou resolvendo a questão de exibição direto no Java, testando se a cada iteração o produto é o mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente isso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

Comment: Grande @WictorChaves, seguindo as dicas que estão neste link que você passou deu certo sim. Agora tem que marcar como resolvido? Posto a resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função **GROUP_CONCAT(expr)** do MySQL.

Sua query SQL ficaria nesse estilo:

```
select p.descricao,
  GROUP_CONCAT( (select descricao from item where item.codigo = c.codigoItem) SEPARATOR ',' )
from produto p inner join composicao c on c.codigoProduto = p.codigo 
inner join item i on i.codigo = c.codigoItem 
group by p.descricao
order by p.codigo
```

Você pode ver mais sobre a função e seus detalhes na documentação:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Muito obrigado @Lucas pela resposta e pela atenção! Realmente eu não conhecia a existência da função GROUP_CONCAT!

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer desta forma, usando `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
select p.descricao, 
       (select
       GROUP_CONCAT(i.descricao  separator ', ')
       from item where item.codigo = c.codigoItem)
       as items  
from produto p inner join composicao c on c.codigoProduto = p.codigo 
inner join item i on i.codigo = c.codigoItem 
group by p.descricao
order by p.codigo
```

A função `GROUP_CONCAT` irá agrupar os resultados das condicionais na mesma linha usando um separador especificado, no caso `", "` (vírgula seguida de espaço).

Resultado (testado no MySQL-Front):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Obs.:** para não parecer cópia, estava escrevendo a resposta quando a outra  foi publicada. Como ambas ficaram parecidas mas com uma construção e
>   um resultado um pouco diferente, resolvi manter esta resposta ativa como opção.

Comment: Grande @Sam! Eu agradeço muito a atenção dada para o meu problema! Realmente eu desconhecia a função GROUP_CONCAT. Deu certo para resolver!